# Java script. How much memory is allocated in the array if you push only the value of index 100

Tags: javascript, browser

I thought about this question when I solved an algorithmic problem.

For example:

```
const arr = [];
arr[100] = 1;
```

how much memory is allocated in the array if you push only the value of index 100? 100 elements or 1?

If there is a link to the documentation

Comment: `If there is a link to the documentation` - did you search for any? p.s. you aint pushin nuttin ... you're setting the value of `arr[100]` - there is no "push"

Comment: The would highly depend on the engine being used. If we're talking v8 then https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds would be a good start to start digging in.

Comment: JavaScript arrays usually act more like maps do in other languages: they are key-value mappings first ("associative array"). Specific runtimes might optimize specific use-cases to act as "real" arrays, if they can, but that's definitely not the default.

Answer (score 0):

Quick test in the console yields us this:

```
arr[100] = 1
console.log(arr)
// prints: (101) [empty × 100, 1]
```

According to this article every empty slot takes up 8 bytes each with the average number taking up 9.72 bytes and 48 bytes of overhead:

https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/07/24/javascript-array-object-sizes.html

Makes a total of roughly 857.72 bytes.

Comment: Which javascript engine?

Comment: @JaromandaX Chrome, so v8